# rpc.lockd daemon not available in NFS client server

Tags: rhel, nfs

I have installed `nfs-utils` package on my NFS client server and successfully mounted the NFS volume.

However, I can't see the NFS's rpc.lockd daemon running. For an application I plan to run on the share, I require the `lockd` service.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to be running NFS version 4?  If you are running RHEL 7, then I believe NFSv4 is the default which IIRC does not use rpc.lockd anymore

Comment: I think so. Can you give me the steps to run v3 and enable rpc.lockd please.